# How to find the solutions to the inequality $ \tan x < 2 $

Tags: functions

I have

> $$ \tan x < 2 $$

what are its solutions? (solution-set)

**What I've done?**

> $$ \tan x -2 < 0$$

Now, by analysing the sign-change, or wavy-curve method

[image: as 2 is the critical point]

> So $$ \tan x \in (- \infty, -2) $$

Now-
**how to find $x$?**

**EDIT:** I would prefer an algebraic method, but in response to a comment I would like to  add the required graphs

Comment: Just draw the graph $y=\tan x$ and the line $y=2$ in the same picture. Now what can you read off from that...?

Comment: @HansLundmark i thought so, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @HansLundmark Ok, wait

Comment: as Hans said the best method to solve these problems is just plot the functions and then see which function is above and where etc...

Comment: do you want the solution or just an hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to help with a drawing:
[image]

We deduce the general solution:
$$x\in\bigcup_{k\in\mathbf Z}\Bigl(\frac\pi2+2k\pi,\arctan 2+(2k+1)\pi\Bigr)\cup\Bigl(-\frac\pi2+2k\pi,\arctan 2+2k\pi\Bigr).$$

Comment: Do you think this will work when I have only a sheet of paper & a pen?

Comment: @RaviPrakash: Why? I can tell you it was longer for me to translate my drawing into a proper LaTeX code than to write the solutions from a hand made drawing. Just  replace colours with different hatchings.